# Angular no me actualiza todas las pantallas con SignalR

Tags: html5, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

Cómo están? Vengo por un problema que tengo entre Signalr y Angular. Mi tema es que cuando alguien hace un pedido, quiero que todas las pantallas que estén suscriptas al hub, llamen a un método para dibujar de nuevo los elementos. El tema, es que funciona hasta cierto punto. Cuando se realiza el pedido, la pantalla del usuario que lo hace, si se redibuja, pero, las demás pantallas de otros usuarios, no, solo lo hacen cuando se hace click o se abre la consola. No se que pasa, ya seguí muchos tutos y ninguno me da la respuesta que busco. Acá dejo todo el código posible:

Controller:

```
    namespace Susy_Beer_House.Controllers
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Susy_Beer_House.Hubs.HubsPedidos;
    using Susy_Beer_House.Interfaces.Bussines;
    using Susy_Beer_House.Models.Request;
    using Susy_Beer_House.Models.Request.SignalRModels;
    using Susy_Beer_House.ModelsDB;

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class PedidoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<HubPedido> _hubContext;

        private readonly IPedidoBusiness _pedidoBusiness;
        public PedidoController(IPedidoBusiness pedidoBusiness,
                                IHubContext<HubPedido> hubContext)
        {
            _pedidoBusiness = pedidoBusiness;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("AgregarPedido")]
        public ActionResult AgregarPedido(AgregarPedidoRequestModel listaPedidos)
        {
            var idUsuarioActual= ObtenerUsuarioActual().Id;

            listaPedidos.idUsuario = idUsuarioActual.Value;

            var resultado = _pedidoBusiness.AgregarPedido(listaPedidos);

            if (resultado>0) {                

                _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("CambiarEstadoMesa", listaPedidos.IdMesa.ToString());
            }

            return Ok(resultado);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("ObtenerDetallePedidos")]
        public ActionResult ObtenerDetallePedidos([FromBody] int idMesa)
        {            
            return Ok(_pedidoBusiness.ObtenerDetallesPedidos(idMesa));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("AgregarDetallePedido")]
        public ActionResult AgregarDetallePedido(AgregarPedidoRequestModel listaPedidos)
        {
            var idUsuarioActual = ObtenerUsuarioActual().Id;

            listaPedidos.idUsuario = idUsuarioActual.Value;
            return Ok(_pedidoBusiness.AgregarNuevoDetallePedido(listaPedidos));
        }
        private Usuarios ObtenerUsuarioActual()
        {
            return new Usuarios()
            {
                Id = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid)?.Value),
                UsuarioNombre = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace Susy_Beer_House.Hubs.HubsPedidos
{
    public class HubPedido : Hub
    {
       
    }
}
```

Front Hub Service:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";  
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class HubPedido {

  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection; 

  respuestaRecibirPedido: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor(@Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string,) {
    this.respuestaRecibirPedido = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  }

  public startConnection = () => {
    console.log("Apunta a: "+this.baseUrl);
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.baseUrl +"hubPedido")
      .build();
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err))
  }

  public agregarListenerRecibirPedido = () => {
    this.hubConnection.on("CambiarEstadoMesa", (data) => {
      console.log("Respuesta de hub: " + data );      
      this.respuestaRecibirPedido.next(data);
    });
  }

}
```

Front Listado a actualizar:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MesaModel } from '../../../modelos/MesaModel';
import { MesasService } from '../../../services/mesas/mesas.service';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { GenerarPedidoComponent } from '../modales/GenerarPedido/generar-pedido.component';
import { HubPedido } from '../../../HubsService/HubsMozos/HubPedido';
import { CambiarEstadoMesaHubModel } from '../../../modelos/HubsModels/CambiarEstadoMesaHubModel';
import { NotificacionesService } from '../../../services/Notificaciones/notificaciones.service';
import { DetallePedidoComponent } from '../modales/detalle-pedido/detalle-pedido.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagina-principal-mozo',
  templateUrl: './pagina-principal-mozo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagina-principal-mozo.component.css']
})
export class PaginaPrincipalMozoComponent implements OnInit {

  breakPoint=5;

  arrayMesas: MesaModel[];

  pruebaEscuchandoHub: any;

  constructor(private mesasService: MesasService,
    private dialogGenerarPedido: MatDialog,
    private hubPedido: HubPedido) {
    this.ObtenerMesas();
  }



  ngOnInit() {

    this.breakPoint = (window.innerWidth <= 400) ? 1 : 5;
    this.hubPedido.startConnection();
    this.hubPedido.agregarListenerRecibirPedido();
    this.hubPedido.respuestaRecibirPedido.subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.ObtenerMesas();
      }

    });
  }

  ObtenerMesas() {
    this.mesasService.ObtenerMesas().subscribe(respuesta=> { 
      this.arrayMesas = respuesta;
    });
    console.log("Array");
    console.log(this.arrayMesas);

  }

  onResize(event) {
    this.breakPoint = (event.target.innerWidth <= 600) ? 1 : 5;
  }

  AbrirModalAgregarPedido(idMesa: number, nroMesa: number) {

    let mesaEncontrada = this.arrayMesas.filter(mesa => { return mesa.id === idMesa });
    
    if (mesaEncontrada[0].mesaEstado === 'Libre') {
      let dialogo = this.dialogGenerarPedido.open(GenerarPedidoComponent, { disableClose: false, autoFocus: true, width: "60%", data: { IdMesa: idMesa, NroMesa: nroMesa } });
    }
    else {
      let dialogo = this.dialogGenerarPedido.open(DetallePedidoComponent, { disableClose: false, autoFocus: true, width: "60%", data: { IdMesa: idMesa, NroMesa: nroMesa} });
    }
    
    
  }
}
```

Front HTML:

```
<h5>Mesas</h5>

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Seleccione Mesa</mat-label>
  <mat-select ngIF="arrayMesas">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <div *ngFor="let mesa of arrayMesas">
      <mat-option value="{{mesa.id}}" (click)="AbrirModalAgregarPedido(mesa.id, mesa.nroMesa)">{{mesa.nroMesa}}</mat-option>
    </div>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-grid-list cols="{{breakPoint}}" rowHeight="2:1" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let mesa of arrayMesas">
    <mat-grid-tile>
      <div [ngClass]="mesa.mesaEstado==='Libre'?'mesas-menu mesas-menu-libres':'mesas-menu mesas-menu-ocupada'"
           (click)="AbrirModalAgregarPedido(mesa.id, mesa.nroMesa)">
        {{mesa.nroMesa}}
      </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </div>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: Ya modifique el componente de mi html de esta Forma:

export class PaginaPrincipalAdministradorComponent implements OnInit { 

  private signalRSubscription: Subscription;

  datosPruebas: any = "Nada Por ahora";

  constructor(private hubPedido: HubPedido) {
    this.signalRSubscription = this.hubPedido.getDatosAdmin().subscribe(
      (datos) => {
        console.log(datos);
        this.asignarValor(datos);
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }
  asignarValor(valor) {
    this.datosPruebas = valor;
  }

}

Comment: y aun no entiendo porque el valor si se muestra en consola, pero, no en la variable que tengo para mostrar en el html :(

Answer (score 0):

Después de varios días sin dormir (cosa normal en la programación :D), logre dar con la solución, la dejo acá por si alguien mas le pasa:

```
export class HubPedido {

  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection; 

  public respuestaRecibirPedido= new EventEmitter<string>();

  public avisoAdmin = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(@Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string,) {
    this.crearConexion();
    this.suscribirOnListeners();
    this.iniciarConexion();
  }

  private crearConexion() {

    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.baseUrl + "hubPedido")
      .build();
  }

  private iniciarConexion() {

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));

  }

  private suscribirOnListeners() {
    this.hubConnection.on("CambiarEstadoMesa", (data) => {
      this.respuestaRecibirPedido.emit(data);
    });

    this.hubConnection.on("AvisarAdmin", (data) => {
      this.avisoAdmin.emit(data);
    });
  }
```

y en el componente le agregue NgZone:

```
export class PaginaPrincipalAdministradorComponent implements OnInit { 

  aviso: string[] = []; 

  constructor(private hubPedido : HubPedido,
              private _ngZone: NgZone)
  {

    this.suscribirEventos();

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  private suscribirEventos() {
    this.hubPedido.avisoAdmin.subscribe(data => {
      this._ngZone.run(() => {
        this.aviso.push(data);
      });
    });
  }
}
```